# How can I set up a socket with an IP outside my router in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, ip

I am using this code to create the connection with server, with a PC (my Server) connected to the same WiFi as my laptop (my Client):

```
sock=new Socket("192.168.0.103", 44422);
```

But if I am willing to connect to an IP which is connected to another public IP with address for example `122.172.189.166` and a local IP address of `192.0.168.15`, how to go about it?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can't. You need to have control over the machine which is home to the external address (which you have) and set up a port redirection.

Comment: You have to connect to the public IP. If it belongs to a router then the router has to be configured to forward inbound connections to the server's private LAN IP. There is nothing you can do about that on the client end.